# How to create new columns repeatedly in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create columns using current data.
But I can only do just one column currently in my code.

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {


  myeval <- function(text){
    eval(parse(text=text))
  }

  
  newvar <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    var_name <- input$var
  
    mtcars %>% transmute(!!var_name := round(rowMeans(select(., input$sel)),digits = 2))
  
  })
  
  output$view <- renderReactable({
    reactable(newdf())
  })
  
  newdf <- reactive({
    bind_cols(
      mtcars, newvar()
    )
  })
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(data=TRUE)
  
  
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    newdf()
  })
  
  
  output$view <- renderDataTable(
    options=list(scrollX=T),{
    newdf()
  })
  
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste("dataset-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(newdf2(), file)
      
    })
  
}
)
```

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rlang)


shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = ""
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      textInput("var","New Variable name"),
      selectInput("sel","select", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = T),
      actionButton("go","mean"),actionButton("go2","sum"),

    ),
    tags$br(),
    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput("view"),
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download data'),
      selectInput("sel2","X Variable", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = T),
      selectInput("sel3","Y Variable", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = T),
      
      uiOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
)
)
```

I'm trying to create a new variable in reactive data, showing in `dataTableOutput` to check whether column creation succeeded.

I have no idea how to make new variables repeatedly in my shiny app.
Is there any way to create new columns with current columns in reactive data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create new columns repeatedly, please see the code below.  Please note that you still need to update your program for sum button and downloadbutton, as I have only fixed adding new columns per your OP.  Also, I have put a reset button, incase you want to start all over again adding new variables.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rlang)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = ""
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        textInput("var","New Variable name"),
        selectInput("sel","select", choices = names(mtcars), multiple = T),
        actionButton("go","mean"),actionButton("go2","sum"),
        actionButton("reset","reset")
      ),
      tags$br(),
      fluidRow(
        dataTableOutput("view"),
        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download data'),
        selectInput("sel2","X Variable", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = T),
        selectInput("sel3","Y Variable", choices = names(mtcars),multiple = T),
        
        uiOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    
    rv$data <- mtcars
    
    myeval <- function(text){
      eval(parse(text=text))
    }
    
    newdf <- eventReactive(input$go, {
      req(input$go,input$var,input$sel)
      var_name <- input$var
      mtcar <- rv$data
      newvar <- mtcar %>% transmute(!!var_name := round(rowMeans(select(., input$sel)),digits = 2))
      rv$data <- bind_cols(mtcar, newvar)
    })
    
    output$view <- renderReactable({
      req(newdf())
      reactable(newdf())
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      rv$data <- mtcars
    })
      
    output$view <- renderDataTable(
      options=list(scrollX=T),{
        newdf()
      })
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { 
        paste("dataset-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(newdf2(), file)
        
      })
    
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted!